# how to have space between two specific columns in h:panelgrid

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
<f:facet name="header">
 <h:outputText value="Customer   Information"/>
</f:facet>


<h:outputLabel value="Title" /><h:outputText  value="#{addProductBean.title}"/>

<h:outputLabel style="width: 80px" value="Date of Birth" />
<h:outputText   id="dateofbirth" value="#{addProductBean.dateOfBirth}" size="10"  maxlength="100"/>


<h:outputLabel value="First Name" /><h:outputText id="firstname" value="#  {addProductBean.firstName}" size="10" maxlength="100"/>

<h:outputLabel value="Gender" /><h:outputText id="gender" value="#{addProductBean.gender}" size="10" maxlength="100"/>

<h:outputLabel value="Last Name" /><h:outputText id="lastname" value="#{addProductBean.lastName}" size="10" maxlength="100"/>

</h:panelGrid>
```

In the above I want a space between title dateofbirth and in similar other fields is that possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  columnClasses to define style for each column

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="a,b,c,d">

    .a{
        width:80px;
     }
     .....
```